# How to Add Symbol for every second word

Tags: go

while playing codingame I was facing a question:

You'll receive a string like this

> `"Mario Lee SecondStreet 13 12234 Belgium"`

And your Code response should look like this:

> `"Mario Lee| SecondStreet 13| 12234 Belgium|"`

Can you guys help me to find the necessary functions to get this output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How is the problem related to the tag google-app-engine-golang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play here: https://play.golang.org/p/tNx6ZPVRktZ

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := "Mario Lee SecondStreet 13 12234 Belgium"

    var output string

    for k, v := range strings.Split(input, " ") {
        if k%2 == 1 {
            output = output + "|"
        }

        output = output + v
    }

    output = output + "|"

    fmt.Println("output: ", output)
}
```

Output:

```
output:  Mario|LeeSecondStreet|1312234|Belgium|
```